# What is print-read consistency?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

And how important is it, when defining a `print-object` method?

For example, it appears to me that `hash-table` instances in SBCL violate this principle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Print-read consistency says, in CL, that if [`*print-readably*`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/v_pr_rda.htm) is true, then printing an object should either:

- produce a printed representation which is *similar* to the object when read with the standard readtable in effect;
- or signal an error of type [`print-not-readable`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/e_pr_not.htm#print-not-readable).

**Similarity** has a slightly complicated definition, because it is necessarily not definable within a single image, since the whole purpose of it is to allow objects to be printed and then later read in another image.  It is defined in [3.2.4.2](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bdb.htm) of the spec, although all of [3.2.4](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/03_bd.htm) is worth reading.  Note in particular that implementations are allowed to extend the definition of similarity.

Note that there are some lacunae in my definition above: in particular I think that the other printer & reader control variables need to have standard values for `*print-readably*` to make sense (for instance `*package*`, `*read-default-float-format*` and so on.  [`with-standard-io-syntax`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_std_.htm) is the tool you want here.

Finally note that similarity is defined for multiple images *of the same implementation* in some cases.  For objects whose readable printed representation is not defined by the standard, an implementation is allowed to print things such that another instance of *itself* can reconstruct a similar object: it doesn't have to ensure that other implementations can.

What all this means is that if you are defining a mechanism for printing an object then, if `*print-readably*` is true, it should either print the object in such a way that a similar object will be read (in the same implementation perhaps), or signal an appropriate error: what it should *not* do is quietly print the object in an unreadable way or in a way such that reading the representation does not return a similar object.  A good way of doing this is to use [`print-unreadable-object`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_pr_unr.htm) whose whole purpose is to ensure this for you.

Hash tables may or may not be printable readably.  In SBCL they are:

```
* (defvar *h* (make-hash-table))
*h*
* (setf (gethash 'foo *h*) 1)
1
* *h*
#<hash-table :TEST eql :COUNT 1 {1002CE5863}>
* (with-standard-io-syntax (print *h*))

#.(SB-IMPL::%STUFF-HASH-TABLE (MAKE-HASH-TABLE) (QUOTE ((FOO . 1)))) 
#<hash-table :TEST eql :COUNT 1 {1002CE5863}>
```

The `#.(...)` form will recreate a similar hashtable when read, in SBCL (but only in SBCL).

In another implementation (Clozure CL), hash tables are not printable readably:

```
? (defvar *h* (make-hash-table))
*h*
? (setf (gethash 'foo *h*) 1)
1
? *h*
#<hash-table :test eql size 1/60 #x3020012A119D>
? (with-standard-io-syntax (print *h*))

> Error: Attempt to print object #<HASH-TABLE :TEST EQL size 1/60 #x3020012A119D> on stream #<SYNONYM-STREAM to *TERMINAL-IO* #x302000B9DC1D>
```